# MediaController for VideoView on Custom Dialog not shown - Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller, customdialog

I am trying to show a mediacontroller for a videoview which exist on a custom dialog. But somehow the mediacontroller does not appear. I have seen few questions related to this, but havent found any suitable answer for it yet.

Is it happening because I am trying to show the mediacontroller on the custom dialog?

If yes then is there any workaround for same?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activity` instead of `DialogFragment` and set the Activity theme in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: Yes but I have already done a lot of coding using custom dialog, no way to do it with existing dialog?

Comment: I think there is no other way to do it with `DialogFragment`. And please do let me know if you find the solution.

Comment: This was a good idea for me, I spent many hours trying to show the controls in the `DialogFragment` without success. But when I change to `Activity` this works right away. I use this theme for my dialog actyvity: `<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>`

Comment: This is not a real answer to the question.